# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydotplus'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pydotplus

I installed `pydotplus` and `tensorflow` with `pip install pydotplus`
and `pip install tensorflow`.
It displayed:

```
C:\Users\tesfasefineh34>pip install tensorflow
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.1.6 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.43.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.4.0 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.37.1)
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib==0.9999999 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (0.9999999)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach==1.5.0 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (3.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.4 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.4->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (3.7.0)

C:\Users\tesfasefineh34>
```

for pydotplus

```
Requirement already satisfied: pydotplus in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.1 in c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (from pydotplus) (3.0.6)
```

However when I import like this `import tensorflow` and `import pydotplus`
the result is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydotplus'`. Anyone may help me those issues?

Comment: What if you use `python -m pip install pydotplus`?

Answer (score 0):

try uninstall them by using:

```
python -m pip uninstall pydotplus
python -m pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and after do:

```
python -m pip install pydotplus
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

try to check for each one